# I am having trouble with aliasing

Tags: c

I've got a function which is supposed to add a file to a node of a linked list, each file is a structure containing a constant char *name. The function uses parameters of a linked list and a const char[] (which will name of new data struct). Everything goes smoothly until I try to call the function again, the name of my first data gets changed to the new one, I think I am forgetting to allocate memory somewhere. (or I am screwing up with the const chars)

(here's the section of code which puts const char[] new_name into a spot in the list)

```
  node->data_list[node->data_count].data_name = new_name;
  node->data_count++;
```

Comment: Need more information like more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `data_name` is a `char*` and `new_name` is a `char[]` this:

```
node->data_list[node->data_count].data_name = new_name;
```

does not copy `new_name` into `data_name` but just means that `data_name` points to `new_name`. Each `data_name` in the list will be pointing to `new_name`.

You need to `malloc()` and `strcpy()`:

```
node->data_list[node->data_count].data_name = malloc(strlen(new_name) + 1);
strcpy(node->data_list[node->data_count].data_name, new_name);
```

Remember to:

```
free(node->data_list[node->data_count].data_name);
```

when no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `new_name` points the same buffer every time you call the function, so successive calls end up changing the old buffer which the old node still points to.  You need to use malloc to allocate a new buffer each time.